# sharing data members between two application in c#

Tags: c#

I want share data between two application in c#. I have done it using IPC and text file read and write.But I want two share data rather than it.

Comment: Your question is not clear. Could you elaborate?

Comment: suppose i have string variable like "Name" in dll. If I set the name in application then it is reflected also in another application.

Answer (score 4):

You can use:

1. Local DB and connect both applications to it
2. Shared file
3. [Net pipe](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/696413/First-date-with-WCF-Named-Pipe-Transport-Duplex) to connect applications (search NetNamedPipeBinding and DuplexChannelFactory)